# Convert seconds to readable time string

Tags: java

I need to take a long value that represents seconds and return it as a readable string. I've already accomplished this, however my catch is that I need it to only return the units that were used. For example, if I input "1209600" seconds which is 14 days, I need it to only return "14 days" instead of "14 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds". If I input "1209601" seconds which is 14 days and 1 second, I need it to only return "14 days 1 seconds" etc.

What is the best way to go about this besides multiple if statements checking for 0 values? Here is what I have so far:

```
public String getDurationString(long duration) {

    long days = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(duration);
    duration -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(days);

    long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(duration);
    duration -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours);

    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
    duration -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes);

    long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(duration);

    return String.format("%d day(s) %d hr(s) %d min(s) %d sec(s)", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with 4 simple if statements?

Comment: @JBNizet Nothing wrong with it I suppose, just seeing if there was another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggestion I will give to use a if condition for every timeunit and something like a String Builder to create the final message.

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long duration = 1209622L;
    long days = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(duration);
    duration -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(days);

    long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(duration);
    duration -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours);

    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
    duration -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes);

    long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
    
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder( );
    if (days!=0) {
        msg.append( days+" day(s)");
    }
    if (hours!=0) {
        msg.append( hours+" hours(s)");
    }
    if (minutes!=0) {
        msg.append( minutes+" minutes(s)");
    }
    if (seconds!=0) {
        msg.append( seconds+" seconds(s)");
    }
    System.out.println(msg.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it just by calculation is as follows:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    long input = 1209660L;
    long days = input / 86400L;
    long hours = (input % 86400L) / 3600L;
    long minutes = (input % 86400L % 3600L) / 60L;
    long seconds = input % 86400L % 3600L % 60L;
    System.out.print((days != 0) ? " Days: " + days : "");
    System.out.print((hours != 0) ? " Hours: " + hours : "");
    System.out.print((minutes != 0) ? " Minutes: " + minutes : "");
    System.out.print((seconds != 0) ? " Seconds: " + seconds : "");
}
```

Output:

```
Days: 14 Minutes: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This return statement will fulfill your requirements, Just replace it

```
 return String.format("%s %s  %s  %s ",
                days!=0?days+" day(s)" :"",
                hours!=0?hours+" hr(s)":"",
                minutes!=0?minutes+" min(s)":"",
                seconds!=0?seconds+" sec(s)":"");
```